# Dynamic url rewriting in a JavaEE JSF application

Tags: java, url, jsf, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

The application is deployed and in operation. The user, named John, comes to the login page - "my-site.com/login.xhtml", and logs in. We get the data about it from the database and must redirect it to the main page of the application - "my-site.com/main.xhtml". At the same time, in the address bar it should have a URL consisting of the data (its name) that we just received from the database, like this - "my-site.com/john".

There are wonderful [prettyfaces](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) and [rewrite](https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) libraries that are designed to solve such problems, but unfortunately for redirection they need to know what URL to display (user name) during the deployment of the application, but of course we do not know it until the user is logged in.

Please help me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this tutorial and use variable templating and query parameters.

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/README.md

as copied from above link and modified:

```java
return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
    .defineRule()
    .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("/{p}")))
    .perform(Forward.to("/main.xhtml?user={p}"));
```

and let a Cdi bean handle the user parameter.